# Textures from Data in HTML in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get the URL images in HTML to create multiple blobs in an scene.
Here a fiddle for the example.
[Textures from Data in HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/zhampu/tpnoer3w/1/)

In the console I get :
    `Uncaught ReferenceError: sphere is not defined`
anybody has any tip on why is not working?

Thanks

Comment: In your animate function you have `sphere.rotation.y += 0.001`, but sphere is defined in the `makeBlob` function. Meaning that sphere is only available in the `makeblob` scope. Changing `let sphere` to `var sphere` will probably do the trick

Comment: Like @2pha says, it will do the trick as `sphere` and `update` variables are defined within a scope of the `makeBlob` function and not visible globally or inside any other function.
`var` should do, but I would suggest you to define those variables (`sphere` and `update`) globally for a better practice and scope understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update you code to the latest version of `three.js` (`R115`) and also removed the scoping issue that introduced some runtime errors.

```js
const v = new THREE.Vector3();

// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector('#c'),
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
})
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)


//Scene & Camera
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
camera.position.z = 10

const sceneElements = [];
const spheres = [];

// Data Diagram
document.querySelectorAll('[data-diagram]').forEach((elem) => {
  const sceneTexture = elem.dataset.diagram
  const eachTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(sceneTexture)
  sceneElements.push(eachTexture)
  return sceneElements
})

function makeBlob(sceneElements) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sceneElements.length; i++) {
    const sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 32, 16).toNonIndexed()
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: sceneElements[i]
    });
    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material);
    sphere.position.x = i * 3;
    scene.add(sphere);
    spheres.push(sphere)
  }
}

makeBlob(sceneElements)

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)

  let time = performance.now() * 0.0005;

  for (var i = 0; i < spheres.length; i++) {

    var sphere = spheres[i]

    let k = 1;

    var positionAttribute = sphere.geometry.getAttribute('position')

    for (var j = 0; j < positionAttribute.count; j++) {

      v.fromBufferAttribute(positionAttribute, j);
      v.normalize().multiplyScalar(1 + 0.3 * noise.perlin3(v.x * k + time, v.y * k, v.z * k))
      positionAttribute.setXYZ(j, v.x, v.y, v.z)

    }

    positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true

  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

animate()
```

```css
#c {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}
*[data-diagram] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  height: 3em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/teaf/blob/v4/js/perlin.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<p>
 <span data-diagram="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/200/300.jpg" class="left"></span>

</p>
<p>
 <span data-diagram="https://i.picsum.photos/id/376/200/300.jpg" class="right"></span>

</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
this totally helped but I'm a bit confused with the positioning of the spheres.
can I change the position of them with my mouse? is it ok to use only one canvas for this?